# Objectify Query grandchildren relations

Tags: objectify, google-cloud-datastore

Suppose we have the following entities:

```
 @Entity
 @Cache
 public class Site{
     ....
 }

 @Entity
 @Cache
 public class Page{
     @Parent
     private Key<Site> parent;
 }

 @Entity
 @Cache
 public class Comment{
     @Parent
     private Key<Page> parent;
 }
```

What is the best way to query after the list of comments of a Page, having the Page id and Site id?  I have tried .ancestor() method but this only accepts the Site entity,throwing a

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Keys.getMetadataSafe(Keys.java:61)
```

if I supply a Page entity instead. `ancestor (site)` is not good enough for this case, as I need the comments for a specific page. The only solution I can think about is to add a new attribute in the Comment entity `Long pageId` and `@Index` it and then use filter to get the comments of a page. Is there a better solution?  Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing wrong here. You can certainly perform ancestor queries by any parent in the hierarchy. Perhaps the entity you are passing in does not have an id? Try passing in a Key instead.

Comment: That said, it's generally a poor architectural practice to use `@Parent` so deeply nested. It's usually better to leave everything as separate entities and carefully pick `@Parent` relationships.